# Run jBehave story n number of times

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I have a jBehave/Selenium story which has certain steps (e.g. to create a record)

Now I want the same steps to be run n number of times (i.e. i want to create n records)

How can I do that in jBehave?

I am using Selenium WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

I think the normal way to execute the steps in a story n number of times is to have an examples table containing n rows: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/story-syntax.html.

Another solution might be to have a step "When n records are created". The implementation of this step just calls the code of the steps needed for the creation of a record n times.